# Does $(1+|\lambda|)^m\leq C_m |\lambda|^m$ hold for every $\lambda\in (0, 1)$ and $m\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $\lambda\in (0, 1)$. Is there for every $m\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$ a constant dependening on $m$ but not on $\lambda$ such that $$(1+|\lambda|)^m\leq C_m |\lambda|^m?$$

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want:
$$ \left(1+\frac{1}{\left|\lambda\right|}\right)^m \leq C_m $$
but $\sup_{\lambda\in(0,1)}\left(1+\frac{1}{\left|\lambda\right|}\right) = +\infty$, hence there is no constant that does the job.